# How can I create a subset of the 'most dissimilar' arrays from a set of possible combinations?

Tags: python, arrays, math, numpy, combinations

Say I have an array of `shape (32,)`.

Each element can have one of four `int` values:`0` to `3`

If I wanted to create an array for each possible combination I would have 4<sup>32</sup> ( approximately 1.84 x 10<sup>19</sup>) arrays - this is overly burdensome.

Is there a straightforward way to pick fewer arrays, say 1 x 10<sup>6</sup>, by picking the 'most dissimilar' combinations?

By 'most dissimilar' I mean avoiding arrays that are different by one (or few) values and picking arrays that have many dissimilar values.

Also, if there is an area of mathematics that I should be looking at to improve my description please let me know.

Comment: Do you have a measure of dissimilarity? E.g. is `3` less similar to `1` than `2` is, or are they all equally dissimilar to each other?

Comment: @larsmans - they are all equally dissimilar

Comment: For most practical purposes, simply generating random combinations would be sufficient. What do you need to do with this subset of combinations?

Comment: @beaker. It's a long story. Random combinations will probably be sufficient. However, it would be good to know if there is a more rigorous approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find arrays with no position in common with `x` by randomly changing each position to a different value, e.g.

```
>>> x = np.random.randint(0, 4, 32)
>>> x
array([3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2,
       2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3])
>>> (x + np.random.randint(1, 4, 32)) % 4
array([0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3,
       3, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm could look like this:

1. Keep the last X (say 10) of the combinations that have been used in a list of some sort.
2. Pick Y (say 10) combinations randomly.
3. Analyze each of the Y combinations against the last X combinations to find the most dissimilar combination.  This would involve writing a method that would generate a score as to how dissimilar the combination is with each of the last X combinations.  Average the score and pick the one that is most dissimilar.